# IOException from InputStream while trying in separate Thread instead of Main Thread

Tags: java

I have a Client application which connect, write and read some data from a remote server. It's fine when i do all these activities in single (**main**) thread and all the time it write and read data from server. I have 100 remote servers and as long as i am doing connect, write and read individually with 100 servers one after another server i am able to do all 3 activities successfully without any issue. But i am facing problem when i implemented multi threading by creating 100 threads in a loop and doing same connect, write and read to complete the 100 sites execution in parallel. I am able to connect and write but **while reading through InputStream** it's throwing IOException with response code 401. If i put a sleep of 5 to 6 seconds while connecting each server i am able to connect, write and read successfully. I had put a long sleep in the main thread so that all 100 threads will exit their execution successfully. **All 100 servers have different url or IP**. All the above mentioned Connect, Write and Read methods are in one class which implements Runnable. So creating a creating 100 threads in loop will have their own copy of these methods and there is no shared resource involved. Can you please guide me where am i wrong?

Comment: Please format the question to improve the readability

Comment: from what you posted , the only obvious issue is the opposite than what you pointed. *and there is no shared resource involved* , maybe not , there is somewhere a resource shared , and when you are trying to test it concurrently , it fails. In order to be more precise , and let the others help you too , please post the code, with the snippets in which you think that the issue might be. Also your title suggests that a resource(`InputStream`) is being shared along the application's threads

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Below is the code.public class MainClass
{
 // This will load the urls to connect to server
 loadProvisionalData();
 for (int serverCnt = 0; serverCnt < 100; serverCnt++)
 {  
  urlCon = new UrlConnection(dbData, serverCnt, this); 
  Thread t = new Thread(urlCon);
  t.start();
 }
 
 while(true)
 {    
  CommonUtil.sleep(1000000);
 }
}

Comment: Not able to add the full code... so adding only the read part which shows error.                                                                                      public void readData(URLConnection conn, String siteId)
 {
  try
  {
  conn.setReadTimeout(10000000);
  conn.setConnectTimeout(6000);
  bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null)
  {
  log.info("Line - " + line);
  }
  }
  catch (IOException ex)
  {
  log.error("Error Inputstream in "+ this + ex);
  }
 }

Comment: can you please tell me how to add full code as i am not able to add full code due to number of max characters limit in the comment box.

Comment: Looks like no body is showing interest to give a possible solution. So i am posting my problem in another way. I am getting IOException with status code 401 while testing only with multiple thread and not with single thread. Can any body suggest why it is so? 401 mean unauthorized. However same authentication token is sent in case of single thread.

Comment: I think i posted a question in a wrong forum.. Thanks...